# Sending data to sockets in an arraylist of Sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking, output

I have made a chat server that my clients can connect to but the clients don't get the messages the other sent. This is the code that does it all. Sending and receiving and setting up output streams.

```
public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < ClientConnector.Connections.size(); i++)
        {

            try
            {
                if(Socket != null)
                {
                    ObjectOutputStream Output = new ObjectOutputStream(Socket.getOutputStream());
                    ObjectInputStream Input = new ObjectInputStream(Socket.getInputStream());
                    whileChatting(Input, Output);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void sendMessage(String message, String returnedMessage, ObjectOutputStream out)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("[Server] " + message);
        if(!message.isEmpty())
        {

            out.writeObject("\247c[Server]\247d " + message);
            out.flush();
            System.out.println("[Chat] Sent: " + message);
        }
        else
        {
            out.writeObject(returnedMessage);
            System.out.println("[Chat] Sent: " + returnedMessage);
        }
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("[Info] Flushing remaining data to stream.");

    }
    catch(IOException ioException)
    {
        System.out.println("[Warning] Error: ioException @ sendMessage line 76.");
    }
}

public static void whileChatting(ObjectInputStream input, ObjectOutputStream output) throws IOException
{
    String message = "";
    do
    {
        try
        {
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            System.out.println(message);
            sendMessage("", message, output);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException)
        {
            System.out.println("[Warning] Error: ClassNotFoundException @ whileChatting line 1-7.");
            System.out.println("idk wtf that user sent!");
        }
    }while(!message.equals("/stop"));
}
```

I am wondering. How would i make this send what one person sends to all the clients? I keep a list of sockets in an array list of sockets. That looks like this.

```
public static ArrayList<Socket> Connections = new ArrayList<Socket>();
```

As each client connects it stores their Socket it this list. If there is a better way of doing this then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If these are remote clients, then a [MulticastSocket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html) might do the trick.  If these are local clients, then a publish/subscribe messaging service like [HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq) would work (clients subscribe to the message queue, and HornetQ takes care of the routing).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of the loop, when you don't make any use of the iteration variable. Surely you should be sending to `ClientConnector.Connections.get(i)`?

Another problem here is that you are creating a new `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` on every iteration. That won't work. You must use the same pair of those streams per socket for the life of each socket, at both ends.